# How does Javascript interact with HTML via document.getElementById?

Tags: javascript, html

I hope that I'm not asking a question that has been answered before - I was unable to find anything regarding this subject specifically.

I've been tasked with creating a "Hangman" game via Javascript.  My professor has given us an HTML markup of the game, as well as styled it with CSS.  I have to write the Javascript to make the game work.  The code is contained within an external file.

The HTML has a form that accepts the initial word for hangman:

```
<div id="enterWordContainer" align="center">
Enter a six letter word for hangman:  <input id="hangManWord" type="text" value="" />
<input type="button" value="Submit" onclick="saveWord();"/> </div>
```

How do I begin to manipulate the text that I would input in my HTML document?

I've tried creating a variable that would contain the text:

```
var userGuess = document.getElementById("hangManWord").value;
```

Shouldn't this put the form's input into a Javascript variable?

Comment: yes it should, where do you have that code? Note: that it does not do it continuely, ie when the user changes the input that variable will not be updated to it, you will need to setup an `onchange` event, or execute that code in like the `saveWord()` function if it is not already

Comment: I've tried "getting" the Id at the start of my external Javascript file.  I declare the variable (userGuess) and try to put the value of the element (hangManWord) into the new variable.  So now, the variable should contain whatever was input into the form box and submitted.  I've tried to make a loop statement immediately following the variable declaration.  Something like "if userGuess.length == 6, then alert."

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When executed right after (or at) page load, the assignment `userGuess = document.getElementById("hangManWord").value` sets the variable `userGuess` to the empty string, because that’s what the `value` property is set to, due to the HTML attribute `value=""`.

When the `input` control is used by the user to change the value, this will not change the value of the `userGuess` value.

Within the `saveWord` function, you can use `document.getElementById("hangManWord").value` to get the current value of the control. You *cannot* get the value before a value has been input, though. You can, if you wish, use e.g. `var userGuess = document.getElementById("hangManWord")`, creating a reference to the `input` element (a reference to the whole element node object, instead of just getting the current value of one property thereof) and then use `userGuess.value` later.

Comment: This "saveWord()" that happens on click - I can't find it anywhere else.  Would this be a function that I need to declare within Javascript?  Declare it to make a variable and to assign it the value of the hangManWord element post-click?  Once that value is stored, shouldn't I be able to make logical statements about that stored value in the variable?

Comment: Yes, you have to write it, as part of the assignment “to write the Javascript to make the game work”. You may need to read a JavaScript tutorial before trying this.

Comment: That's fine.  I've been doing the tutorials, but things are very different when inheriting the HTML pre-made.  Having to work off of the provided markup is new for me.

Answer (score 0):

Yes it will put form's input into the userGuess variable. BUT you have to insert your code into form submit event handler and this is function "saveWord();" that i believe you have to implement.
What it will eventually do is get your input value only when it has been submitted.